# Unable to load 3rd party lib in Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, error, static-resources

I'm trying to import a 3rd party javascript library from static resources in my lightning web component.
I followed the exemple given in LWC [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_third_party_library).

I encounter the folowing error :

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(ViewModel)' of undefined
>
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: m is not a function

My sample code :

```js
import loadScript from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import fuse from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/fuse';

export default class SelectActivity extends LightningElement {

    fuseLoaded = false;

    renderedCallback() {
        if(!this.fuseLoaded){
            console.log(fuse);
            loadScript(this,fuse + "/fuse.js")
                .then( () => {
                    this.fuseLoaded = true;
                })
                .catch( error => console.log(error));

        }

    }
}
```

And my static resource is present :

[image: Static resource]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a path variable in your loadScript call (/fuse.js) which is required when you want to load a file inside an archive
When you upload the javascript file directly (which is the case based on your screenshot) you only pass the import identifier as 2nd argument

```
loadScript(this,fuse)
```

Comment: and then there is also the fact that the library might not be locker service compliant, which might lead to other/similar issues after =/

Comment: Hello, thank you for both of your answers. I tried using @Renji-XD's line but it gives me the same error.
Furthermore, I don't think that the issue is with Locker Service compliance because a colleage of mine uses this lib in Aura Components without problem.

Comment: that means nothing - i also already encountered stuff which works fine in aura but not in lwc. I tried your lib (assuming it is https://fusejs.io/) and got no error.so i can`t really give any further hints as from my side everything looks ok

Comment: I finally got it to work the problem was that the imported fuse varaible wasn't seen, I had to create a field in my controller class and assin the imported value to it.

Answer (score 3):

As said above, `loadScript(this,fuse)` should work fine.

Adding to it, you should not load script in `renderedCallback` as it will be invoked for every api/track variable change (unless it needs to like in case of graph where graph changes with every parameter change).
You should be using `connectedCallback` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by removing the promise part from the loadScript.
This below code only is enough as earlier answered by @salesforce-sas

```
loadScript(this,fuse)
```